# File1 cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file A.cab

Tags: build, wix

Our organization is going to implement WIX for creating the installer. So i applied dark.exe to get  WXS from the MSI. I am able to create the MSI using this the WXS. When i tried to install i am getting the following error.

```
Error 1334. The file 'File1.bmp' cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file A.cab.
```

i double checked and confirmed that the file is there inside the cab. Stucking badly with this error for a long time

If i am puttingthe cab outside the MSI then the installation is working.